# API for creating Application User in JBoss

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I assume there is an API somewhere that the adduser command uses. I want to create users in my application. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The logic of password hashing is implemented in JBoss SASL `UsernamePasswordHashUtil` class. Look at [GitHub](https://github.com/wildfly-security/jboss-sasl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/sasl/util/UsernamePasswordHashUtil.java).

Sample usage:

```java
import org.jboss.sasl.util.UsernamePasswordHashUtil;

UsernamePasswordHashUtil util = new UsernamePasswordHashUtil();
System.out.println(userName + 
    "=" + 
    util.generateHashedHexURP(userName, realm, password));
```

There is also a possibility to use a simple property file with "`username=password`" rows. Just set security realm attribute "`plain-text=true`".

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=TestRealm/authentication=properties:add(path="/path/to/users.properties", plain-text=true)
```

Comment: Not want I'm looking for, but it may be a useful hint for an alternative solution